# xcache only caching admin files

Tags: php, admin, xcache

I am running xcache (shows as installed in phpinfo).

When I view the admin page, the only php files being shown as cached as those in the admin folder (or those on the current page I am viewing).

[image]

Does anyone have suggestions as to why files might not be caching?
(note: tried installing both xcache 2 and 3 from src.

Comment: How did you use it in your project? Can you put some code here with xcache functions used?

Comment: It's used for caching only - there are no custom calls or custom vars. Just xcache doing it's default compiled PHP caching. It worked on a previous server, just moving to a new server it's having this new issue.

Comment: OK it looks like I was running suphp which is not compatible with xcache (or eaccelerator)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have SuPHP enabled. I had the same exact issue and when I disabled SuPhp, xcache started caching everything just like it should.